# Sub selecciones de SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo que separar y agrupar los resultados de un query por año y por localidad. Ambas fuentes de información están en la misma tabla. Si uso `group by` por año combina todas las localidades, igualmente el inverso. Imagino que la solución es un query dentro de otro pero no encuentro buenos ejemplos del mismo.

Aqui esta la tabla:
[image: La Tabla Original]

Cuando escribo este codigo recibo los campus adicionales desapareacen:

```
SELECT Course_Deliveries.year, Course_Deliveries.campus
FROM Course_Deliveries 
GROUP BY year
```

[image: Cada Año]

Sin embargo si trato de por campus entonces años desaparencen.

```
SELECT Course_Deliveries.year, Course_Deliveries.campus
FROM Course_Deliveries 
GROUP BY campus
```

[image: Cada Campus]

El resultado requerido es:

```
2016 Manawatu
2017 Auckland
2018 Manawatu
2018 Auckland
```

Si uso `GROUP BY year, campus` le da priorida a unos sobre el otro.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverfkow. Siempre es bueno que muestres lo que has intentado, eso ayuda a comprender el problema y agiliza una posible solución.  No sé si sabes que puedes agrupar por varias columnas: `GROUP BY columna1, columna2`

Comment: Si posteas tu código nos ayudaría a darte una solución

Comment: como dijo @A.Cedano tienes que elegir tu primer y segundo group, si quieres invertir la agrupacion, entonces tienes que hacer un segundo query

Comment: Gracias por su paciencia, aqui esta el edit de la pregunta. Espero que ofresca clarificaccion.

Comment: De casualidad es esto lo que buscas: `SELECT cd.year, cd.campus FROM Course_Deliveries cd GROUP BY cd.year, cd.campus ORDER BY cd.year, cd.campus;` ?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si eso trabajo. Ahora, que es el “cd” que usaste al frente de cada término?

Comment: Es el alias de la tabla, puedes ponerle cualquier nombre, te evita escribir el nombre completo de la tabla